# Python - Use a list of string to search for folders names

Tags: python

I have a list of strings (stored in a .txt file, one string per line) and I want to make a script that takes the first line and search all folders names in a directory, and the takes the second line and search all folders names and so on. How do I do this? Hope i made my self clear. Thks!

Answer (score 1):

This example reads paths from text file and prints them out.  Replace the print with your search logic.

```
import os

textfile = open('C:\\folder\\test.txt', 'r')

for line in textfile:
    rootdir = line.strip()
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! your answer with Nurzan's solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by searching all folders you mean printing them out to the standard output you can do this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join


with open('directories.txt', 'r') as f:
    i = 1
    for line in f.readlines():
        directories = []
        tmp = line.strip('\n')
        for d in listdir(tmp):
            if isdir(join(tmp, d)):
                directories.append(d)
        print('directory {}: {}'.format(i, directories))
        i += 1
```

It will output something like this:

```
directory 1: ['subfolder_1', 'subfolder_0']
directory 2: ['subfolder_0']
directory 3: []
```

Note that I recommend using `with` in order to open files since it will automatically properly close them even if exceptions occur.

Comment: @Rafaelpsmed You are welcome. Please, accept someone's answer in order to mark the question as answered.